# Is there a way to copy and paste on the PS4 without using the Keyboard?

Tags: ps4, controllers

For example, I want to copy and paste text from a message on the Browser. I can't do copy and paste because all those paragraphs are not on the PS4 Keyboard to select.

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of the keyboard, there should be a button that looks like it has three dots. Please select that, and then select "select all" or "select text". After then you can click on the three dots, and then hit "Copy".
After that you can paste the same text via that same menu to another text box.